# How can we dismiss an Alert dialogue without ontap or any user interaction?

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to dismiss an alert dialogue when a callback is being called. How can i achieve it?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you elaborate please.

Comment: use `Navigator.pop()` method

Comment: @pskink i tried but now working.

Comment: if your dialog is shown with [showDialog](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showDialog.html) then `Navigator.pop` is the only way to dismiss it - check the [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showDialog.html)

Comment: setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
This _ModalScope<void> widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the framework is already
in the process of building widgets. A widget can be marked as needing to be built during the build
phase only if one of its ancestors is currently building. This exception is allowed because the
framework builds parent widgets before children, which means a dirty descendant will always be
built. Otherwise, the framework might not visit this widget during this build phase. - getting this error while calling pop().

Comment: this is because you cannot call it inside `build` method

Comment: Can you show some code where you tried the above `Navigator.pop()` solution?

Answer (score 0):

One way is you can add timer for it.

Try this code:-

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(GetMaterialApp(title: 'Flutter', home: Flutter()));
}

class Flutter extends StatefulWidget {
  const Flutter({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Flutter> createState() => _FlutterState();
}

class _FlutterState extends State<Flutter> {
  int seconds = 3;
  bool visible = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Flutter'),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Center(
          child: ElevatedButton(
        child: Text('Open Alert'),
        onPressed: () {
          RemoveAlert();
          visible = true;
          Get.defaultDialog(
              title: 'Alert',
              middleText: 'Alert will go in ${seconds} seconds').then((value){
                visible = false;
              });
        },
      )),
    );
  }

  void RemoveAlert() {
    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: seconds)).then((value){
      if(visible){
        Get.back();
        print('removed');
      }else{
        print('removed already');
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Note: I have used get package here.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I got the solution after a long time effort.
I called Navigator.pop(context) two time. Then it worked for me.